# import ansible stdout_lines to python file

Tags: python, list, ansible

I'm trying to copy **ansible output.stdout_lines array to a python file**

```
- name: Fetch routing info
  hosts: Windows
  tasks:
    - win_command: route print
      register: output
    - debug: msg={{ output.stdout_lines }}
    - command: python rInfoPython.py {{ output.stdout_lines }}
      delegate_to: localhost
```

**sample output**

```
"stdout_lines": [
            "", 
            "Windows IP Configuration", 
            "", 
            "   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : test-win", 
            "   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : ", 
            "   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : local",
            "", 
            "Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:", 
            "", 
            "   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ", 
            "   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Xr Device #0", 
            "   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 01-KJ-00-33-22-B0", 
            "   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No", 
            "   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes", 
            "   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : XX.XXX.X.XX(Preferred) ", 
            "   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.XX", 
            "   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ", 
            "   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : XX.X.XX.XX", 
            "                                       XX.X.XX.XX", 
            "   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled", 
            "", 
        ]
```

I want to **copy and print stdout_lines as it is in aligned format to python file to iterate it**

```
import sys
print(str(sys.argv))
```

Kindly help me to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

For that specific purpose, you may be happier using an environment variable, or (of course) write those out to a temp file

```yaml
    - command: python rInfoPython.py
      delegate_to: localhost
      environment:
        the_output: '{{ output.stdout }}'
```

then your script would pull that text in as

```py
import os
print(os.getenv("the_output"))
```

If you insist on attempting to pass in a rich structure via a string like that, then JSON encoding it will preserve the formatting without a bunch of shell wizardry

```yaml
    - command: python rInfoPython.py {{ output.stdout_lines | to_json | quote }}
      delegate_to: localhost
```

```py
import json
import sys
text = sys.argv[1]
lines = json.loads(text)
print(f"received {len(lines)} lines")
```